# Watson Studio: Not processing images

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I am unable to complete the labs in the IBM computer vision class. I see these errors on the the IBM cloud.

- Module 2; Lab: Classifying images with IBM Watson Error in Watson Visual Recognition service:  Internal Server Error

  ## Internal Server Error - Write

  The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

  Reference #4.3696f648.1608776368.905f1257
- Module 3; Lab: Testing and Training a custom classifier Error encountered while training. Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Internal Server Error - Write The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Reference #4.4496f648.1608778902.7801fb22 Timestamp 11:01:42 AM

Can you help recommend what I must do? Thanks in advance.

- Enoch David

Comment: When did you provision your Watson Visual Recognition service?

Comment: I moved the Watson Studio and Watson Visual Recognition services under Dallas, it works now. 

It was previously under Tokyo.

Thanks.

- Enoch